# How to change font colour on Variant excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code that takes a cell value such as <0.2 and discards the 'less than' symbol and returns half the numeric portion e.g. 0.1

This works well but I want to indicate the cells that have been changed by making the font colour red.

I can't get the formatting applied.  I have tried a few variations on the code below but get a run-time error 424 object required, on the formatting line. `MyVar = MyVar.Font.ColorIndex = 3`

````
Sub RemoveLessThanSpedUp()
'
'
'Values with Red Text were reported as less than the method detection limit and are shown here as one-half the detection limit
'
Dim r As Range
Dim Datarange As Variant
Dim Irow As Integer
Dim MaxRows As Long
Dim Icol As Integer
Dim MaxCols As Long
Dim MyVar As Variant

Datarange = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
MaxRows = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
MaxCols = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
    For Irow = 1 To MaxRows
        For Icol = 1 To MaxCols
            MyVar = Datarange(Irow, Icol)
            If Left(MyVar, 1) = "<" Then
            MyVar = (Right(MyVar, Len(MyVar) - 1)) / 2
            MyVar = MyVar.Characters.ColorIndex = 3
            'MyVar.Font.ColorIndex = 3
            Datarange(Irow, Icol) = MyVar
            
            End If
        
    Next Icol
    Next Irow
Range("A1").CurrentRegion = Datarange
End Sub```
````

Comment: Did you try`Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Cells(Irow,Icol).Font.Color=vbred` instead of `MyVar = MyVar.Characters.ColorIndex = 3`? `Myvar` is an array, not a range object, according to your code, so you can't use it to change colors

Answer (score 1):

Try the next adapted code, please. Your code uses an array, which is not bad in terms of speed, but it does not handle ranges which have a `font` property. Coloring many cells may take a lot of time. I will build an array to be filled with the modified cells address, which will be dropped on the first column after the existing one:

```
Sub RemoveLessThanSpedUp()
Dim r As Range, Datarange As Variant, Irow As Integer
Dim MaxCols As Long, MyVar As Variant, MaxRows As Long, Icol As Long
Dim sh As Worksheet, i As Long, arrEr, k As Long

Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here what you need

MaxRows = sh.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
MaxCols = sh.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
If sh.Cells(1, MaxCols).Value = "Errors" Then
    sh.Cells(1, MaxCols).EntireColumn.Clear
    MaxCols = MaxCols - 1
End If
Datarange = sh.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
ReDim arrEr(MaxRows * MaxCols)
    For Irow = 1 To MaxRows
        For Icol = 1 To MaxCols
            i = i + 1
            MyVar = Datarange(Irow, Icol)
            If Left(MyVar, 1) = "<" Then
                MyVar = (Right(MyVar, Len(MyVar) - 1)) / 2
                arrEr(k) = sh.Cells(Irow, Icol).Address(0, 0): k = k + 1
                Datarange(Irow, Icol) = MyVar
            End If
        Next Icol
    Next Irow
    
    If k > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve arrEr(k - 1)
        sh.Range("A1").CurrentRegion = Datarange
        With sh.Cells(2, MaxCols + 1)
            .Offset(-1).Value = "Errors"
            .Resize(k, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arrEr)
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Nothing to be corrected..."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes i was using a loop previously and it was too slow on large datasets. I tried the code above and  I get Run-time error 1004: Method Range of object '_Worksheet' failed, for the line `Set rngCol = sh.Range(Irow, Icol)`

Comment: @flashliquid: Ups... I will immediately correct it. Corrected. Please, test the updated code...

Comment: @flashliquid: Didn't it work (now) as you need?

Comment: @flashliquid: Glad I could help! But we here, when somebody answer our question supplying a "much much faster" code, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works...

Comment: Hi yes, I did accept this answer but further testing resulted in the macro hanging/ excel not responding with a test data set of a few thousand rows so I unaccepted it and am writing this.

Comment: Not any problem, if it does not work as you need. But I do not imagine a reson for freezing Excel. If not confidential, can you share the test workbook? I will tell you where the problem is and also maybe trying to optimize the code.

Comment: Plese, use [this](https://easyupload.io/) transfer site. It is free and easy to be used.  I am waiting for the download link, from some minutes...

Comment: @flashliquid: The code is extremely fast in terms of eliminating first "<" character and dividing the remained value. It looks that building a discontinuous range of about 12000 areas takes a lot. If this amount of cells to be corrected is the real case, I would suggest to renounce at the font coloring. Excel only looks freezing, because of the necessary very long time to process the Union range. If patient enough, it will finally finish the job. Adapted the code to return the corrected cells address in a column after the last existing one.